# Allow indexes on subfolder from root htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, directory, indexing

I want to add Indexes to a specific subfolder from my root-htaccess. Because of the CMS I use I can't put that htaccess into the subfolder as one would normally do.

I tried this

**/.htaccess**

```
<Directory /path/to/subfolder>
    Options +Indexes
</Directory>
```

but it results in an internal server error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Apache manual :
`Context:   server config, virtual host`, so obviously you can not use this directive in `.htaccess`

[Apache manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory)

Answer (score 1):

You could put an empty index.html file in the folders you don't want to show indexes. Kind of the other way around, but it might work for you.